# Is there any way to copy a text from another program without Select it?

Tags: c#, api, winapi, sendmessage, sendkeys

I want to copy text from other program,
in this program Ctrl+a is considered for other command, and I can't use " SendKeys.SendWait("^a");" to select the text.

Is there any way to copy that text?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [UIAComWrapper](http://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/), you will need handle to that window (from where you are trying to copy) and information about that element which you can get from [UIAutomationVerify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/).

```
var elementCollection = AutomationElement.FromHandle(windowHandle).FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, Condition.TrueCondition);
foreach (var item in elementCollection)
{
   //check item properties if element is the one you looking for
}
```

Also, instead of `Condition.TrueCondition` you can provide more complex filter to get only that one element.

**Edit**, added real example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
const string InternetExplorerClass = "IEFrame";
static void Main()
{
    var windowHandle = new IntPtr(0);

    //Find internet explorer instance
    windowHandle = FindWindow(InternetExplorerClass, null);

    if (!windowHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        //create filter to improve search speed
        var localizedControlType = new PropertyCondition(
            AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty,
            "tab item");

        //get all elements in internet explorer that match our filter
        var elementCollection =
            AutomationElement.FromHandle(windowHandle)
                .FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, localizedControlType);

        //iterate through search results
        foreach (AutomationElement item in elementCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Current.Name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Internet explorer not found");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Code above will find Internet Explorer and will print all tab titles to console. I put source code to [GitHub](https://github.com/floatas/UIAutomationExample).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I should research about your Idea. I hope this problem will be resolved by your Idea.

Comment: If you need any more information about this library let me know, I used it in my several projects.

Comment: Can you please tell me more? How should I use it?

Comment: Why are you using a UI Automation wrapper with C#, when there's System.Windows.Automation providing the same technology (UI Automation)?

Comment: @andlabs [System.Windows.Automation uses old API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302979/4208209)

Comment: I could not understand how to use that idea. @floatas

Comment: @SaMi Sorry, but I am currently at work, I may assist you more after work.

Comment: @floatas ooh, that's interesting; thanks for the tip! I'll keep it in mind for future assistance.

Comment: @floatas Let me try it, and I back you. Thank you very much.

Comment: in " new PropertyCondition(
            AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty,
            "tab item"); " What other things can I substitute "tab item" ? @floatas

Comment: It can be anything, you can use UIAutomationVerify (mentioned in post) to find which properties are set for that control and use it in this filter.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of editor is that, and why you can't just get source file? Maybe that will work:
   1. Place cursor on the start of the first line
   2. Hit Ctrl+Shift+End
   3. Ctrl+C

Alternatively, you can try to simulate keyboard input through [Windows Input Simulator library](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. it className is: AfxOleControl42. Ctrl+Shift+End does not work in this app. Is there another way?

Comment: Dear cyberj0g I am researching about your Idea. Thanks for it.

Comment: Why my InputSimulator just has Equals and RefrenceEquals, and has not SimulateKeyDown or other methods?

Comment: Faking input is usually wrong, for many reasons. In this particular case it is wrong, because you won't be able to copy text without selecting it. Which is one of the requirements.